# supported codecs in android

Tags: android, codec

which codecs are supported for audio in android? G711 is supported. But is there any other like G729,...etc?

Comment: it would be helpful if you were to be more specific as to what type of codec you want: audio/video etc. but for the complete list, check out the list in the answer below.

Comment: It would be helpful to know something more about the application you have in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Im not sure if G.729 is explicitly available. But it might be used as a module in one of the other codecs that are listed on the page above.
HTH,
Sriram.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodecInfo.html

Have a piece of code which tell's all the avaible codecs (audio and video) in the device.

```
private List<String> mSupportedCodecs;
private void getSupportedCodecs() {
    int numCodecs = MediaCodecList.getCodecCount();
    mSupportedCodecs = new ArrayList<String>(numCodecs);
    for (int i = 0; i < numCodecs; i++) {
        MediaCodecInfo codecInfo = MediaCodecList.getCodecInfoAt(i);
        mSupportedCodecs.add(codecInfo.getName());
    }
}
```